nl80211 mesh_point vs adhoc: Key Differences
I'm trying to understand the fundamental differences between nl80211 mesh_point and nl80211 adhoc modes in the context of Linux Wi-Fi drivers. While both seem to involve peer-to-peer connectivity, I'm unclear about their specific use cases, network topologies, and underlying mechanisms.
Could someone elaborate on the following:

Performance implications: Are there significant performance differences between the two?
Use cases: When would one choose mesh_point over adhoc, or vice versa?
Directly connected nodes: How does communication between two directly connected nodes differ in these modes? Are there any protocol or handshake differences?
Any code examples or specific driver implementations would be greatly appreciated.
Tags: linux, wifi, nl80211, mesh, adhoc, networking

